# Direct to action in lieu of 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, single-page-application

I'm making a single-page-application and the way I have it set up is that using a base controller in the OnActionExecuting() method I redirect non-ajax requests to the home index action.  The path will still be there and used as an indicator to tell the javascript what to do.

That works fine for something like /login where there is actually a /login page that would normally be accessible if I hadn't blocked it using the technique I mentioned.

However when I take it a step further and use /some/other/meaningful/but/bogus/url which has no route/controller but has some meaning to the javascript, I get a 404 error.

So obviously what I'd like to do, is in that 404 situation I would like to just load the home index action instead.   Alternatively a replacement for my ajax blocking that redirects all paths to the home index action (unless they're valid routes called with ajax) would have the same result.

I've searched for similar answers, unfortunately the same wording is frequently used to describe questions regarding custom 404 pages, so it's a tough one to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **do** want a custom error page. The difference is your custom error page is a controller/action. A custom error page doesn't have to be a page like `notfound.html` it is just a url so you can set the url to a controller action.

The code below will redirect unhandled status codes to "/home" i.e. the home controller. Then for 404 it will go to /controller/action which could be `/home/notfound`.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/home">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/controller/action"/>
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

---

The non-redirect route, in your `global.asax.cs` add the following code. This example maybe a little heavy but essentially achieves what you want in that the custom error controller is executed but the URL is unchanged.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    var currentController = " ";
    var currentAction = " ";
    var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }

        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }

    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    var controllerFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    var controller = (Controller)controllerFactory.CreateController(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, "Error");
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var action = "Index";

    if (ex is HttpException)
    {
        var httpEx = ex as HttpException;

        switch (httpEx.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 401:
                action = "Unauthorized";
                break;
            case 403:
                action = "Forbidden";
                break;
            case 404:
                action = "NotFound";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    httpContext.ClearError();
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() : 500;
    httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = action;

    controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
    ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and found that the URL in the address bar changed.  Is that the behaviour you would have expected?  If so I think you've misread my question :P    On the client side there should be no sign of a redirect, this is essential to maintain the JavaScript functionality described.

Comment: @braks updated with some `global.asax.cs` code that will achieve what you are after.

Comment: That's more like it!  I like this method as it's quite customisable.  One thing though I had to change `Setup.GetControllerFactory();` to `ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();`

Comment: @braks I'll update the question, the code is quite old probably mvc 4 :P